# how can i access device on dhcp server from outer net

Tags: networking, routing, iptables, raspberry-pi, dhcp-server

i made DHCP server on rpi with following settings:
for interface eth1:

```
interface eth1
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/20
static routers=192.168.1.0
```

and for dnsmasq.config

```
interface=eth1
bind-interfaces
server=8.8.8.8
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=192.168.1.60,192.168.1.70,12h
```

ive also enabled net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
and

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE  

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

and added this to /etc/rc.local

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

i have device connected to the dhcp server, which has the ip of 192.168.1.64.
My wlan0 (on the rpi) ip is 192.168.14.3.
My pc ip is 192.168.14.4.
The uestion is how can i access the device that is connected to rpi with eth1 (ip of 192.168.1.64) with my pc that is on 192.168.14.4?
i tried ip scanning and the device doesnt show up on 192.168.1.1-254
also i cant modify settings in the router

i made a subnet in rpi because thats the only way i saw i can share wlan0 internet with eth1 so both the device and the rpi is connected to the internet, using the rpi also as "converter" wifi to ethernet
i tried bridging but internet on the rpi its self isnt connected but the device is

Answer (score 0):

I see a few weird things.

Firstly

```
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/20
```

Why such on elaborate subnet ? This is for IP's ranging from 192.168.0.1 all the way to 192.168.15.254 (some 4000 hosts) with broadcast on 192.168.15.255 Unless you are very aware of what you are doing, you likely want to change it into

```
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
```

Which puts in the 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254 range with broadcast on 192.168.1.255

For the easiest way to get network devices to talk to eachother, they should be kept in the same subnet. Your subnet can be wider (like your /20), but it will complicate things a little if you are just beginning to learn about networks.

Secondly, I think you have misconfigured your DHCP range. In dns-masq.config you have

```
dhcp-range=192.168.60,192.168.1.70,12h
```

which is missing a 1 in the first part, so should become

```
dhcp-range=192.168.1.60,192.168.1.70,12h
```

Comment: ive read in other website that since the /24 is limiting who can talk to the subnet 192.168.1.1 -254 so thats why i putted there so that device on 192.168.14.4 can talk to 192.168.1.64, and the missing 1 was missing here so ill update it

Comment: i made this subnet because that the only way i saw that i can share internet connection between wifi to ethernet, by creating dhcp server

Comment: I see. It is correct that they can communicate in the /20 subnet, but that means all your devices need the same subnet mask. Can you find the rpi from your PC for example ? If not, your PC isnt in the same subnet and needs to be changed. Also, i'm sorry if i'm pointing out things you already know and understand, its just hard for me to gage how much you do or dont know :)

Comment: i appriciate any kind of help, and please assume that im dont know much about networks  yes um able to see the rpi from my pc in 192.168.14.3, i was able to send ssh, but i dont want to do it through ssh (although i can do it so it will be automatically) i really prefer not to, also importent thing is that wlan0 (the net that is connected to both pc and rpi has net mask of 255.255.255.0) i think i need to change that although im not sure how since its settings comes from the router

Comment: You  can calculate the subnet by hand, or use some online subnet calculator. The netmask for the router would become 255.255.240.0, but it shouldnt be necessary. Afterall, you have tried to configure your rpi to do the "bridging" for you, thats what the iptables and forward are for.

Comment: you mean the main wifi network? the one that gave me the 192.168.14.3 to the rpi?